# Cakephp table query

Tags: forms, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have a `members` table. It has these columns:

- ID
- fname
- lname
- parent
- spouse

I want 'parent' field to have select option in a form which uses 'fname' & 'lname' and store it in 'parent' field. I have tried to do this Members controller:

```
$results = $this->Members->find('list', 
           array('order'=>array('fname DESC')));

$parent = $results->toArray();
```

I am calling `$parent` variable as an input. However that method doesn't work. I don't know how to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

When calling list you can configure the fields used for the key and value with the **keyField** and **valueField** options respectively.

Doc: https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#finding-key-value-pairs

Like this

```
$query = $articles->find('list', [
    'keyField' => 'slug',
    'valueField' => 'title'
]);
```

In your case it will be like this

```
$results = $this->Members->find('list', array(
    'keyField' => 'ID',
    'valueField' => 'parent'
    'order'=>array('fname DESC'),
));

$parent = $results->toArray();
```

Comment: I have already done that but when try to pass $parent variable to add.ctp. it does not show the listed input. All I want is all the members' first names to be shown as a drop down list in input 'parent' field in my form.

Comment: @AbhiLeuva can you provide the add.ctp code for better understanding